# How to Avoid that Label Covers Icon?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to render both house numbers and icons for sirens on a map in QGIS. Now I have added two layers with siren nodes and building outlines, the siren layer being *above* the buildings.

In the label rendering options of the house numbers, I have activated "**Discourage labels from covering features**", but still the house numbers are shown above the siren icons. Here is an example:

[image: QGIS: Icon covers label]

Can somebody tell me how I can give the siren icons a higher priority so that they cover the house numbers? The house number label could even be omitted entirely in this case, that would not be a problem.

Comment: Try with one of the nightly QGIS releases. This has been improved with the upcoming 2.14 release

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent text labels from overlapping other markers?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27412/how-to-prevent-text-labels-from-overlapping-other-markers)