# Regrouping concat labels with overlapping intersecting geometries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, clustering, intersect, concatenation

All the fields i want to show on the map are in the same layer.
All the labels have to be showed on the map.
But the concentration is high.

**So i would like to concat the labels when geometries are intersecting. I cannot get intersecting the current geometry with his layer without itself.**

I tried to use Overlapping and geomoverlap with rulesbased labeling but nothing works.

The result could be  : resulting label = "label 1 || / || label 2 ||/|| label 3"
Could you show me the way?

Comment: Would you like to concatenate more attributes into one label? Add an expression to the label text instead of single attribute. Use || operator to concatenate attribute text. You can issert line breaks, too.

Comment: Yes i know  label 1 || // || label 2 :)  My question is how to get the label 1,2,3 . i edit my question Tks

Comment: I would try it in PostGIS "SELECT label1 || label2 || label3 from mytable as t1 where exists (Select * from mytable where ST_Intersects(t1.geom mytable.geom) and mytable.id <> t1.id and ST_Area(ST_Intersection(t1.geom, mytable.geom)) > 0.0001". Probably it won't be wery fast because of the correlated enbeded query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution in QGIS 2.18.3 with clustering methode.
Here are the steps:

1. Create clusters as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211106/clustering-points-polygons-based-on-proximity-within-specifed-distance-using-q)  with a buffer of your choice with *@row_number*
2. Create an *intersect* and a *whitin* with *join attributes by location* tool of the polygons included in the clusters with parameters *summary of the intersected entities*, no statistics, *keep only common records*. Now you have the polygons cluster's number
3. Create relation on the polygons (childs) on the cluster number (parent) between the clusters on cluster number. Check the relation is working with *Identify Features* tool.
4. Use *field calculator* with _relation_aggregate_ in the **cluster layer** `relation_aggregate('relation_name','concatenate',to_string("child_field_for_labelling"),' / ')`
5. Show these labels in cluster layer but hide the polygon style.