# QGIS - Label Rectangle/Buffer Overlapping Layer Above

Tags: qgis, layers, buffer

When I apply a buffer or rectangle to my labels they show through the overlying layers. Is there any way to avoid this, i.e. arrange the label so it lies underneath the layers above? I'm assuming the labels themselves take priority and lie on top of any layers above (I've tried playing with the various priority settings). The yellow layer below has some transparency. I want to include a space around the label so it blocks the underlying contour line, but I don't want the buffer or rectangle showing through the yellow layer.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this in QGIS since it places labels above all other layers. The solution I came up with when faced with a similar problem is to (under Labels→Buffer) set Size to 1.0mm, Color to white, Transparency to 25%, and Blend mode to Hard light. You can see some examples of this at https://alexkent.info/boreas/maps  Take a look at the bottom-right map there; all of its labels are done this way (click the thumbnail to view it full-size).

Comment: Correction, the labels on that map use Size 0.5mm, Transparency 50%, Blend mode Normal.  The idea is the same though; just enough of a buffer to make the letters readable without obscuring the underlying map.

Comment: IMO not possible in QGIS map canvas, but you can achieve this in the map composer: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230671/symbols-above-labels-in-map-qgis